# During installation, do I need an ethernet cord to connect to the internet?

Tags: installation, laptop

I have a Dell inspiron 1525 and was wondering if I needed an ethernet cable to connect to the internet during installation of Ubuntu? Or is an ethernet cable required to connect for the first time after installation?

Answer (score 5):

This question is fairly vague, but in brief, the answer is "no" - the Ubuntu installer will allow you to pick a WIFI network for installation. Even then, a connection to the internet is only recommended, not required, to complete Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 3):

Your family model, the [Dell Inspiron 1525](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron_1525) all come with a wireless network card. They either have a:

- Broadcom 4312 Based Card
- Dell Wireless 1397 802.11g Half Mini-Card (Based on Broadcom 4312)
- Dell Wireless 1490 802.11a/g/n Full Mini-Card (Based on Broadcom 4311)
- Intel Next-Gen 4965AGN 802.11a/g/n Wi-Fi Card

If you happen to have a Dell with the Intel 4965 chip then the wireless card should work out of the box. If you happen to have any of the others then I suggest you [read this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx) which covers all models here and more.

So there is no need to use a ethernet wired connection except in the case that the wireless card needs proprietary drivers (Not detected or installed during installation), in which case, you need a wired cable connection to download all updates and drivers for your wireless card (And anything missing for it) before disconnecting the cable and using the wireless card.